# PyQt: QWhatsThis, display HTML page with image

Tags: python, html, image, pyqt

I want to display a contextual help/doc with **QWhatsThis** from a **HTML file** with embeded **image**; but the image is not displayed.

According to the documentation 
[QWhatsThis Class Reference](https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/PyQt4/qwhatsthis.html), 
QWhatsThis allows rich-text input; rich-text is a subset of HTML4, the page from PyQt4 documentation 
[richtext html subset](https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/PyQt4/richtext-html-subset.html) 
in unavailable, but according to Qt5 documentation 
[Supported HTML Subset](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html), 
the tag:

```html
<img src="image.png" width="42px" height="314px"/>
```

is supported.

Here is the minimal working example I wrote :

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt4 WhatsThis display image")
        self.setGeometry(500, 200, 300, 250)  # left, top, width, height

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        button = QPushButton("Click me", self)

        with open("doc.html", 'r') as fr:
            html_doc = fr.read().decode('utf8')
        button.setWhatsThis(html_doc)

        hbox.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and the HTML page with an image I want to display:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Repère pour les angles du champ de vitesse en entrée</h1>
        <p>Voilà de l’aide !</p>
        <img src="image.png" width="512px"/>
        <p>Bla bla bla</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried three different configuration:

- Python 2.7.5, PyQt4
- Python 3.7.7, PyQt4
- Python 3.7.7, PyQt5

and I get the exact same output, *i.e.* the image is not displayed:

Screenshot when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> with cursor over the button

[image]

What is the problem?
Does *QWhatsThis* really supports image?
Is there something to add to the HTML file?

NB: The python source is the one for *Python 2.7.5* and *PyQt4*; all the sources are available on [*Google drive*](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sWbjfKjNJyGr-YUprgSXrete-XvtJoXs?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because the width attribute you don't have to point to "px" but only the value since the tooltip uses QTextDocument which only supports [some HTML4 features](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html). So you must change:

```html
<img src="image.png" width="512px"/>
```

to

```html
<img src="image.png" width="512"/>
```

[image]